# Вычитание строк

Tags: java, строки

Вычитанием строк назовем операцию при которой все буквы вычитаемого вычеркиваются из уменьшаемого, а если в уменьшаемом таких букв не было они дописываются в конец уменьшаемого в порядке обхода вычитаемого от 0 индекса к последнему.

Например: abcdef - abcfonpq = deonpq или abcdef - fedcloj = abloj или abcdef - fealobjm = cdlojm

**Пример:**

```
Ввод 1: abcdef abcfonpq

Вывод 1: deonpq

Ввод 2: abcdef fedcloj

Вывод 2: abloj
```

Вроде с точки зрения логики стараюсь все делать правильно, но результат нужный не получается. Подскажите, что в моем коде нужно поправить чтоб заработало?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String text;
    LinkedHashSet<Character> temp = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    text = in.nextLine();
    text = text.replace(" ", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (temp.add(text.charAt(i))) {
            sb.append(text.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Comment: слова у вас два, а оперируете вы фактически одним, зачем-то убирая пробел между двумя словами. ваш цикл с самой первой итерации работает неверно, в первом примере буква `a` добавляется в строку первой, а не должна

Comment: Ну так как я не понял как вычитать символы одного слова из другого, я решил что уберу пробел и попробую повторяющиеся символы убрать...но что-то не так сделал...

Comment: Вам нужно убирать из sb символ, если temp.add(text.charAt(i)) == false.

Comment: Так он наоборот, выводит только те символы, которые есть и в первом и во втором слове. А надо их вычитать...и выводить оставшиеся, которые не повторяются в словах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо создать постфикс, в который будет добавляться символ, если он отсутствует в первой строке, если символ в первой строке присутствует, то из обеих строчек этот символ удаляется.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] strings = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    StringBuilder postfix = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings[1].length();) {
        char c = strings[1].charAt(i);
        if(strings[0].indexOf(c) != -1) {
            strings[0] = strings[0].replaceFirst(""+c,"");
            strings[1] = strings[1].replaceFirst(""+c,"");
        } else {
            postfix.append(c);
            i++;
        }
    }
    strings[0] += postfix;
    System.out.println(strings[0]);
}
```

Второй вариант цикла for (очевидно, более простой и быстрый):

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings[1].length(); i++) {
    char c = strings[1].charAt(i);
    if(strings[0].indexOf(c) != -1)
        strings[0] = strings[0].replaceFirst(""+c,"");
    else
        postfix.append(c);
}
```

Comment: Почему-то именно этот вариант оказался самым "проходным". И мне наиболее понятен. Спасибо!

Comment: Лучше, кстати, StringBuilder использовать. Я изменю ответ.

Comment: я со StringBuilder и начинал делать, но потом запутался...

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text1 = in.nextLine();
    String text2 = in.nextLine();

    Set<Integer> set = text2.chars()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

    Set<Integer> set1 = text1.chars()
            .filter(ch -> !set.remove(ch))
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

    String result = Stream.of(set1,set).flatMap(s->s.stream())
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .mapToObj(i->(char)i)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Comment: Это не работает.

Comment: этот способ просто не объединяет 2 строки в конце операции, он просто делает вычитание. в исправленном виде будет объединять, если нужны повторяющиеся символы , то в коллекторе преобразуйте в лист, а не в сет

Comment: Вот теперь работает.

Comment: `s->s.stream()` можно на `Set::stream` ( имхо, выглядит лучше через :: ) в данном примере

Comment: @Andrew Bystrov да, можно и так, если так больше нравится...

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать просто в лоб как описано в условии:

```
String s1 = "abba";
String s2 = "abbba";
String result = s1;

for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
    String l = s2.substring(i, i + 1);
    if (s1.contains(l)) {
        s1 = s1.replaceFirst(l, "");
        result = result.replaceFirst(l, "");
    } else {
        result += l;
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

**UPD.** будет работать и для повторяющихся символов

Comment: Это не будет работать, если в вычитаемом есть повторяющиеся символы.

Comment: Если что, я не тупой, предыдущая версия не работала для повторяющихся символов.